# jwplayer change the control bar position

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I want to change the control bar position when the captions are on (because the control bar is hiding my captions).

on the jwplayer skin.xml the margin value is 7% and i want it to be 0 when the captions are on.

so i did this:

```
onCaptionsChange: function(event) {
   $('videoplayer_controlbar').toggleClass('caption_on');
});
```

and i added on css:

```
.caption_on{
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

This is working ok but i don't want to use the `!important`.

without the !important the control bar is going to bottom:0 but only for a second and jump right back to bottom: 7%

Comment: I'm guessing you can't do that without using !important. The controlbar's CSS is being refreshed every time the user mouses over the video (for the fadein), and then again a few seconds later (for the fadeout). So your CSS will be overridden every time.

Comment: This is something we are going to fix for html5 mode, as flash mode does not hide the captions.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. so in the future we could manage the control bar position?